# Ending while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

I wrote a small Shotgun app, however, the section of code that needs to stop the game when either the AI (called Genius), the user, or both, are shot, I can't get to work.  What am I doing wrong?  I feel like I over-complicated my code a ton by adding lots of returns with different booleans, in which some are being passed and others aren't.

In testing it right now, the loop ends no matter what if the user move (called string move) equals "f".  In any other scenario, I can not get the loop to end.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Start("r");
        }

        public static string Start(string move)
        {

            Console.Write("Welcome to the Shotgun App\nEnter s for single player and m for multiplayer: ");
            string gameType = Console.ReadLine();

            if (gameType == "s")
            {

                Console.Write("Single Player Controls:\n r = reload\n s = shield\n f = fire\nYou start with 1 ammo\nReady to play?");
                Console.ReadLine();

                int ammo = 1;
                int geniusAmmo = 1;
                string geniusMove = "";
                bool done = false;
                while (!done)
                {
                    Console.Write("\nEnter your move: ");
                    move = Console.ReadLine();


                    switch (move)
                    {
                        case "r":
                            Console.Write("\nYou have reloaded, press enter for Genius\n");

                            ammo++;
                            Console.Write("Your ammo is " + ammo);

                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Genius(geniusMove, move, geniusAmmo, done);


                            break;
                        case "s":
                            Console.Write("\nYou have shielded, press enter for Genius\n");

                            Console.Write("Your ammo is " + ammo);

                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Genius(geniusMove, move, geniusAmmo, done);


                            break;
                        case "f":
                            if (ammo != 0)
                            {
                                Console.Write("\nYou have fired, press enter for Genius\n");

                                ammo--;
                                Console.Write("Your ammo is " + ammo);

                                Console.ReadLine();

                                Genius(geniusMove, move, geniusAmmo, done);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.Write("You don't have enough ammo, try again");
                                done = false;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.Write("\nInvalid move, try again\n");
                            done = false;
                            break;
                    }
                    done = EndLoop(move, geniusMove, done);
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
                return move;
            }
            else
            {
                return move;
            }
        }

        public static string Genius(string geniusMove, string move, int geniusAmmo, bool done)
        {
            Random RandomNumber = new Random();
            int x = RandomNumber.Next(0,3);
            if (x == 0)
            {
                geniusMove = "f";
                geniusAmmo--;
                Console.Write("Genius had decided to fire.\nGenius ammo is " + geniusAmmo + "\n");
                TestMoves(move, geniusMove);
            }
            else if (x == 1)
            {
                geniusMove = "r";
                geniusAmmo++;
                Console.Write("Genius had decided to reload.\nGenius ammo is " + geniusAmmo + "\n");
                TestMoves(move, geniusMove);
            }
            else if (x == 2)
            {
                geniusMove = "s";  
                Console.Write("Genius had decided to shield.\nGenius ammo is " + geniusAmmo + "\n");
                TestMoves(move, geniusMove);
            }

            return geniusMove;

        }


        public static void TestMoves(string move, string geniusMove)
        {
            bool done = false;
            if (move == "s" && geniusMove == "f")
            {
                Console.Write("Nice shield, no one has died yet");


            }
            else if (move == "f" && geniusMove == "f")
            {
                Console.Write("You both died!  Good game!");


            }
            else if (move == "r" && geniusMove == "f")
            {
                Console.Write("No shield!?  You died!  Good game!");


            }
            else if (move == "f" && geniusMove == "s")
            {
                Console.Write("Genius is too good, no one has died yet");


            }
            else if (move == "f" && geniusMove != "s")
            {
                Console.Write("Genius let his guard down!  Good game!");


            }
            else if (move != "f" && geniusMove != "f")
            {
                Console.Write("Keep playing it safe.");


            }
            else
            {


            }

        }

        static bool EndLoop(string move, string geniusMove, bool done)
        {
            done = false;
            if (move == "s" && geniusMove == "f")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (move == "f" && geniusMove == "f")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (move != "s" && geniusMove == "f")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (move == "f" && geniusMove == "s")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (move == "f" && geniusMove != "s")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (move != "f" && geniusMove != "f")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return done;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should terminate if you hit one of the conditions outlined in EndLoop that return true.  What happens when you step through that routine in a debugger?

Comment: The while loop only ends when debugging if the user input was "f"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `done` in a few different places, both in some execution branches in the switch cases, and when calling EndLoop.  The assignment from EndLoop will overwrite any previous assignment, so make that The One Place You Set `done`.

Setting `done` with EndLoop in TestMoves does not have any effect since you immediately return a hard-coded value right after you call EndLoop.

I suggest you follow through EndLoop in a debugger.  If it makes it easier for you to visualize what's happening, you might consider instead printing to the console the input parameters for EndLoop, and which if condition you end up selecting.

Comment: So I edited my code and the same thing is still working.  I took out a ton of returns.

Comment: Did you add Console.WriteLine()'s to help you visualize the program flow, or step through in the debugger to understand why you're not seeing the behavior you expect?

Answer (score 1):

geniusMove will always be an empty string since you are not storing the result of the call to the Genius method.

Either store the result in the geniusMove variable or pass it in by reference

```
public static string Genius(ref string geniusMove, string move, int geniusAmmo, bool done)
```

or

```
geniusMove = Genius(geniusMove, move, geniusAmmo, done);
```